# how to measure stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor

My stepper motor have 4 wire is VEXTA motor 2 phase 1.8"/Step, DC 1.96V, 2.8A. 
when i measure the resistance wire 1 & 2 is 0.8 ohms, 3 & 4 is 0.9ohms.
Is it the correct way to measure the resistance?

Comment: Why do you need to measure the resistance? Do you mean how to check the correctness of connection to a driver?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that means 1 & 2 is your X0 & X1; 3 & 4 is your Y0 & Y1.